# Vertical Align not working on all screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the below code and JS Fiddle that works to align the text and image vertically on all browsers.  However, on some screen resolutions it pushes the header text "TESTER" down below the black line as shown in the screenshot.  Please let me know what I can do to fix this. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/w7ba1vyb/3/

```css
#heading{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;   
}
#header{
    padding: 5px 0 0 0; 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 70px;
    
}
#content{
    width: 57%;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    
}
img{
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    
}
#headtxt{
    font-family; ethno;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 10%;
    
}
#socialshare{
    float: right;
    width: 23%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="heading" >
  <div id="header" >
    <div id="content" >
      <a href="http://www.ccc.com" style="text-decoration: none;
color: transparent;
cursor: none;">
        <img src="images/newlogo200x200.png" />
      </a>
      <span id="headtxt" >
        TESTER
      </span>
    </div>
  <div id="socialshare" >
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/ccc" target="_blank"><img src="marketing/fbwhite.png" width="48px" height="48px"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/ccc"  target="_blank"><img src="marketing/twitterwhite.png" width="48px" height="48px"></a>
<a href="http://www.instagram.com/ccc"  target="_blank"><img src="marketing/igwhitev1.png" width="48px" height="48px"></a>
</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

[image: image below showing how the text and image get pushed down in other resolutions]

Comment: `vertical:align` doesn't align elements within the element it's applied to. It applies to elements within the same container.

Comment: I figured it out, just had to add line-height: 50px; to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#heading{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;   
}
#header{
    padding: 5px 0 0 0; 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;

    display:table;
    height: 70px;

}
#content{
    width: 57%;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:1%;

}
#headtxt{
    font-family; ethno;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff;
    color: black;
    display:inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left:10%;

}
#socialshare{
    float: right;
    width: 23%;
    padding: 5px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/w7ba1vyb/8/